# Командная строка не выполняет таски

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-7

Решила освоить Gulp. Столкнулась с такой проблемой - установка прошла успешно, но не выполняются таски, выдает сообщение " Gulp не явлется внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом".

До этого переименовывала системную папку с кириллических букв на латинские.
В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 2):

Может кто-то столкнется с такой проблемой на стадии "новичка-новичка", поэтому расскажу, что сделала я.

Для начала, установив gulp, столкнулась с проблемой, что он выдавал ошибку при выполнении таска. После мониторинга этой темы, поняла, что собака зарыта в том, что в пути к этой папке содержится системная папка, чье название было на кириллице, что мешает адекватной работе галпа.

Поменяла имя системной папки, но проблема сохранилась. Только с другим сообщением:*"Gulp не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом"*.

Интуитивно понимала, что проблема, скорее всего залегла во время переименования системной папки. Поискав информации на эту тему выяснила, что необходимо было внести изменения также в дополнительных параметрах системы. А именно в переменной PATH, поменяв значения с кириллицы, которое там осталось, на латинское имя, на которое изменилось.

И все заработало.

Вот такие приключения новичка.

Comment: Плюсанул за женскую интуицию. Но в вашем ответе нету ничего полезного для читателей СО. Как вы задали путь конкретно?) На эту тему, много холиваров разводят. И возникает много вопросов на тему почему не работают глобальные модули.

Comment: @A.Gusev простите, можно пояснить "как я задала путь конкретно"? Мне показалось, что подробно описала, какие действия предприняла)

Answer (score 0):

Можно указать полный путь от папки node_modules

```
node_modules/.bin/gulp.cmd
```

или создать себе локальный файл gulp.cmd с содержимым

```
node_modules/.bin/gulp.cmd %*
```

Comment: Где нужно указать этот полный путь?

Comment: я так понимаю в той папке, где производилась установка npm install

Comment: там есть этот файл

Comment: ну так он запускается?

Comment: если на него кликнуть, то он быстро мелькает и исчезает

Comment: Так и должно быть. Запустите в виндовс командную строку. сделайте cd <каталог, где выполняется работа> и там уже набирайте gulp <ваш таск>

Comment: Решила эту проблему, описала выше ) Спасибо, что откликнулись )